# Can we call explicitly Watch in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, watch

Can we call watch expliciltly in the controller?

Requirements:

Currently there are two angular tree structured checkboxes. one is carriergorup and another one is modes. I'm retrieving mode values based on carriergroup list. whenever the carrier group list is updated automatically modes list is updated for this i used watch.
current functionality is like.

Whenever the carriergroup list is updated then only modes list is updated. Suppose there is no change in the carrier group list, but I want to make a call for watch explicitly. Is this possible?

```
$scope.$watch(
    'carrierGroups',
    function(carrierGroups) {
        alert("in carrier List");
        $scope.selectedCarrierList = [];
        $scope.isAllChecked = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.carrierGroups.length; i++) {
            /*if($scope.carrierGroups[i].checked){
                cntGroupChecked =  cntGroupChecked + 1;
            }*/
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.carrierGroups[i].categories.length; j++) {
                if ($scope.carrierGroups[i].categories[j].checked) {
                    $scope.selectedCarrierList
                            .push($scope.carrierGroups[i].categories[j]);
                }else{
                    $scope.carrierGroups[i].checked = false;
                    $scope.isAllChecked = false;
                }
            }

        }
        alert("$scope.isModesWatch"+$scope.isModesWatch);

        if($scope.isModesWatch){
            $scope.modesList = DashboardsDataService.getModesData($scope.selectedCarrierList);

        }else{
            alert("$scope.filterModesList-->"+JSON.stringify($scope.filterModesList));
            $scope.modesList = $scope.filterModesList;
            $scope.isModesWatch = true;
        }
    }, 
true);
```

Comment: create normal function and use it inside your watch as callback so that you can manually call that from outside.

Comment: @ Jay ShuklaAbove is the watch how can we call explicitly outside can you please provide code for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Like below, you can do this..

```
var myCustomFun = function(carrierGroups) {
            alert("in carrier List");
            $scope.selectedCarrierList = [];
            $scope.isAllChecked = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.carrierGroups.length; i++) {
                /*if($scope.carrierGroups[i].checked){
                    cntGroupChecked =  cntGroupChecked + 1;
                }*/
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.carrierGroups[i].categories.length; j++) {
                    if ($scope.carrierGroups[i].categories[j].checked) {
                        $scope.selectedCarrierList
                                .push($scope.carrierGroups[i].categories[j]);
                    }else{
                        $scope.carrierGroups[i].checked = false;
                        $scope.isAllChecked = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            alert("$scope.isModesWatch"+$scope.isModesWatch);

            if($scope.isModesWatch){
                $scope.modesList = DashboardsDataService.getModesData($scope.selectedCarrierList);

            }else{
                alert("$scope.filterModesList-->"+JSON.stringify($scope.filterModesList));
                $scope.modesList = $scope.filterModesList;
                $scope.isModesWatch = true;
            }
        }

$scope.$watch('carrierGroups',myCustomFun,true);
```

Now where you want to call custom watch function, you can simply call your function.

```
myCustomFun(param);
```